# How to make a SPARKLINE line graph display only the last 7 days, and other time periods, dynamically?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-query-language, sparklines

How to make a SPARKLINE Line graph display only the last 7 days dynamically?
That is, as data, or new rows, keep being added to HISTORY sheet, the SPARKLINE graph advances in order to show always just the last 7 days in the graph.
I imagine there are ways to do that using the number of rows?
But what I am interested is if there is also a way in which regardless of the number of rows, the graph will always show the last 7 days, or any other period of my choice? This is because the data, or new rows with values, will be added randomly: sometimes every hour, sometimes once a day etc.

Also is there a way of choosing between different times periods:
24h, 7 days, 1 month, 3 months, 6 months, 1 year etc. And then the SPARKLINE changes accordingly.

Appreciate any help.

Here is a small file for editing:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: if answer helped you and solved your issue, please accept it by checking the mark: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDBGo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last 7 records:

```
=SPARKLINE(QUERY(QUERY(SORT({HISTORY!B:B, ROW(HISTORY!B:B)}, 2, 0), 
 "where Col1 is not null limit 7", 0), "select Col1 order by Col2"),
 {"charttype","line";"color","#1aded1"})
```

[image]

---

last 7 days:

```
=INDEX(SPARKLINE(QUERY({IFERROR(DATEVALUE(HISTORY!A:A)), HISTORY!B:B}, 
 "select Col2 
  where Col2 is not null 
    and Col1 <= "&INT(MAX(HISTORY!A:A))&"
    and Col1 >= "&INT(MAX(HISTORY!A:A)-6), 0),
 {"charttype","line";"color","#1aded1"}))
```

[image]

---

example for 3 months:

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11o8oVT7yfeWWSGbW9j1l0H4UH1pfnhk2J2_DYybBU4Y/copy)

Comment: This is amazing! Is there a way to add 24h option? Maybe just add 1 day. I will try.